# SQL Server 2000 - How do I add a description to a field via SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I know how to add the description through the server management studio. And i came across some EXEC thing someplace that looked overly complex to add a field description.

in mysql i can just add the *COMMENT 'field comment here'* option to each field in the table create statement... does SQL Server 2000 have such a thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately that overly complicated exec is the only "proper" way to add a description to a column in a MS SQL DB.

The procedure is:

```
sp_addextendedproperty
```

Once you get your head around it it is a fairly simple procedure to use.

here's an example

```
create table dbo.sometable(col1 int, col2 int)

exec sp_addextendedproperty 'MS_Description', 'comments for col1','user', dbo, 'table', sometable, 'column', col1
exec sp_addextendedproperty 'MS_Description', 'comments for col2','user', dbo, 'table', sometable, 'column', col2
```

Comment: you say "proper" are there improper ways to do it that use standard SQL and not a "hidden away" microsoft only  procedure?  It would be great for the SQL to work in both MS and MY without me having to keep 2 version around.

Comment: You could create a table with columnname, tablename, description and then populate/query that as you would any normal datatable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a TSQL statement to add a description to a column on a table, try this:

```
EXECUTE sp_addextendedproperty N'MS_Description', 
        'my description', N'USER', N'dbo', N'TABLE', N'MyTableName', 
        N'COLUMN', N'MyColumnName'
```

Answer (score 0):

See: [Using SQL Server 2000 Extended Properties](http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3361751/Using-SQL-Server-2000-Extended-Properties.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the trouble to use extended properties as mentioned here if you want, but why not just create a table that contains all of that information - a "data dictionary"?